# En java, utilizar una clase diferente dependiendo del sistema operativo

Tags: java, android

Tengo un sistema que trabaja en multi-plataforma, y para poder diseñarla necesito saber como podría ejecutar una clase dependiendo del sistema operativo.

Tengo creado la siguiente funcion sencilla `Public Boolean esandroid(){....}` donde si el sistema es android es true sino fale, De esta manera me he manejado bien colocando if por todos lados, pero no es practico, quiero saber si existe alguna forma de hacer clases dependiendo del sistema operativo por ejemplo.

```
Class reproducir (){ 
...Codigo para reproducir en android...
}
Class reproducir (){
...Codigo para reproducir que no sea en android...
}
```

La idea es que dependiendo del sistema operativo que ejecute la clase correspondiente.

Teniendo dos clases en el ejemplo anterior, se hace referencia a la misma clase, y esta ejecuta la correspondiente al sistema operativo donde opera actualmente.
¿Es posible?

Comment: Redactando ejemplo usando polimorfismo.

Comment: Así rápido y sin darle muchas vueltas un `if` que llame a una clase o a la otra, tendrías que poner `mi.proyecto.com.ClaseAndroid`para identificarla, pero me parece facil sencillo en insisto, a bote pronto creo que te funcionaría

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La programación orientada a objetos te provee de una herramienta muy útil en estos casos llamada ["polimorfismo"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Para tu caso tienes una clase que se llama `reproducir` que tendrá ciertos métodos como `empezar`, `parar`, `pausa`, `getNumCancion`, `getPosicion`, etc comunes:

```
class reproducir {
  private boolean reproduciendo;
  private int posicion, cancion;

  public reproducir() {
    /* Constructor inicializando parámetros comunes */
    reproduciendo = false;
    posicion = 0;
    cancion = 0;
  }

  public void empezar() {
    /* Actualización común de registros internos o estado de
      reproducción */
    reproduciendo = true;
    /* ... */
  }

  public void parar() {
    /* Actualización común de registros internos o estado de
      reproducción */
    posicion = 0;
    reproduciendo = false;
    /* ... */
  }

  public void pausa() {
    /* Actualización común de registros internos o estado de
      reproducción */
    reproduciendo = false;
    /* ... */
  }

  public void pausa() {
    /* Actualización común de registros internos o estado de
      reproducción */
    reproduciendo = true;
    /* ... */
  }

  public int getNumCancion() {
    return cancion;
  }

  public int getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
  }
}
```

Ahora sólo te queda crear las implementaciones dependientes de la plataforma.

Ejemplo Android:

```
class reproducirAndroid extends reproducir {
  public reproducirAndroid() {
    /* Llamamos al constructor padre */
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void empezar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de comienzo */
    super.empezar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en android */
  }

  @Override
  public void parar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de parada */
    super.parar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en android */
  }

  @Override
  public void pausa() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de pausa */
    super.pausa();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en android */
  }

  /* No es necesario implementar getNumCancion ni getPosicion */
}
```

Ejemplo Java SE:

```
class reproducirJava extends reproducir {
  public reproducirJava() {
    /* Llamamos al constructor padre */
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void empezar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de comienzo */
    super.empezar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  @Override
  public void parar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de parada */
    super.parar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  @Override
  public void pausa() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de pausa */
    super.pausa();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  /* No es necesario implementar getNumCancion ni getPosicion */
}
```

Sólo te queda gestionar qué instancia crear realmente:

```
reproducir getInstance() {
  if (esandroid()) {
    return new reproducirAndroid();
  } else {
    return new reproducirJava();
  }
}
```

Esa instancia `reproducir` devuelta podrá hacer `empezar`, `parar` y `pausa` dependiendo de cada plataforma sin tener que repetir una y otra vez condiciones `if` dentro de su código y, además, no tendrás que repetir en cada implementación el código común como `getNumCancion` o `getPosicion` o partes comunes del estado de reproducción en `empezar`, `parar` y `pausa`.

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza el patron de diseño factory. Este patron te permite crear instancias de una misma interfaz con una implementan en concreto pero ocultando la implemetacion y creando los objetos en base a ciertos parametros(en caso de ser necesarios).

Por ejemplo, define una interfaz llamada `Reproductor.java`:

```
public interface Reproductor
{
  void reproducir(string archivo);
  void pausar();
  void cerrar();

}
```

Entonces ahora en base a los tipos de sistemas operativos que soportarias inicialmente, creas una clase que implemente la interfaz.

Para Linux:

```
public ReproductorLinux implements Reproductor
{
  public void reproducir(string archivo)
  {
     // codigo para reproducir en el OS linux
  }

  public void pausar()
  {
     // codigo para  pausar en el OS linux
  }

  public void cerrar()
     // codigo para cerrar en el OS linux
  }
}
```

Windows:

```
public ReproductorWindows implements Reproductor
{
  public void reproducir(string archivo)
  {
     // codigo para reproducir en el OS Windows
  }

  public void pausar()
  {
     // codigo para  pausar en el OS Windows
  }

  public void cerrar()
     // codigo para cerrar en el OS Windows
  }
}
```

Android:

```
public ReproductorAndroid implements Reproductor
{
  public void reproducir(string archivo)
  {
     // codigo para reproducir en el OS Android
  }

  public void pausar()
  {
     // codigo para  pausar en el OS Android
  }

  public void cerrar()
     // codigo para cerrar en el OS Android
  }
}
```

Ahora creas otra clase que se encargara de crear una instancia concreta según el sistema operativo:

```
public class ReproductorFactory
{
  public static Reproductor crearReproductor()
  {
        if(esWindow)
        {
            return new ReproductorWindows();
        }
        else if(esAndroid)
        {
            return new ReproductorAndroid();
        }
        else if(esLinux)
        {
            return new ReproductorLinux();
        }

        else{
            throw new Exception("Este sistema operativo no es soportado");
        }
  }
}
```

Entonces el uso es lo mas simple. Solo llamas el metodo `ReproductorFactory.crearReproductor()` siempre que necesites el reproductor:

```
Reproductor reproductor = ReproductorFactory.crearReproducto();
reproductor.reproducir("c:/sonido.mp3");
```

Nota la inexistencia de `if`. Y si algun dia llegaras a soportar otro OS, solo tendrías que agregar la implementan del mismo y agregarlo al método `crearReproductor()` y listo, no tendrás que hacer mas modificaciones en tu programa entero ademas de ahí.

Comment: Te me has adelantado por segundos xD te llevas mi +1 porque también se puede usar `implements` (aunque en ese caso no se puede "heredar" código común).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Personalmente no me gusta heredar de clases a menos que **obligatoriamente** exista un comportamiento por defecto. De lo contrario siempre utilizaria una interfaz como base, asi puedo emular la herencia multiple.

Comment: Precisamente acabo de terminar una edición explicando la ventaja de tener código común que no tiene porqué repetirse una y otra vez en cada implementación. Dependiendo del caso una forma es mejor que la otra, por eso te llevaste mi punto.