# Problemas con polimorfismo en java

Tags: java, polimorfismo

este problema me surgió a partir de la pregunta [siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/en-java-utilizar-una-clase-diferente-dependiendo-del-sistema-operativo?noredirect=1#comment253026_135448) Tengo el siguiente código de polimorfismo en java y el problema que tengo es que no se ejecutan las clases hijos

Clase Padre "Reproductor"

```
    public class reproductor implements Runnable {
        protected static sboolean pausado = false;
            protected static String temaactual ;
            protected static Integer posiciondepausa;
            protected static boolean ordendereproducir =true;
            volatile boolean muerto = false;
            volatile boolean reproduciendo = false;

            public void reproducir(){
                if (!reproduciendo ){

                String proximotema = com.proximotema();
                empezar(proximotema);
                }
            }
    reproductor getInstance() {
            System.out.println("bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.reproductor.getInstance()");
            if (main.isandroid()) {
                return new reproducirAndroid();
            } else {
                //System.out.println("bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.reproductor.getInstance()");
                return new ReproducirJava();
            }
        }
            public void empezar (String proximotema){
                //reproduciendo = true;
            }
            public void parar(){
                reproduciendo = false;
            }
            public void pausa(){
                reproduciendo = false;
                pausado = true;
            }
         @Override
            public void run (){

                if (verificador ==null) {

                    verificador = new Timer();
                }
                verificador.scheduleAtFixedRate(controlado, 0, 1000);
                //el error esta a continuacion, un bucle que vuelve loca a la memoria

                while (!muerto && ordendereproducir) {
                    reproducir();
                     //System.out.println( "reproducir");
                }
            }
        }
```

Clase hijo "reproducirAndroid"

```
 class reproducirAndroid extends reproductor {
      public reproducirAndroid() {
        /* Llamamos al constructor padre */
        super();
      }

      @Override
      public void empezar() {
        /* Llamamos a la implementación común de comienzo */
        super.empezar();
        /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
      }

      @Override
      public void parar() {
        /* Llamamos a la implementación común de parada */
        super.parar();
        /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
      }

      @Override
      public void pausa() {
        /* Llamamos a la implementación común de pausa */
        super.pausa();
        /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
      }

      /* No es necesario implementar getNumCancion ni getPosicion */
    }
```

Clase hijo "reproducirjava"

```
 class ReproducirJava extends reproductor {
  public reproducirJava() {
    /* Llamamos al constructor padre */
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void empezar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de comienzo */
    super.empezar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  @Override
  public void parar() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de parada */
    super.parar();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  @Override
  public void pausa() {
    /* Llamamos a la implementación común de pausa */
    super.pausa();
    /* Implementamos aquí el método en java se */
  }

  /* No es necesario implementar getNumCancion ni getPosicion */
}
```

Como se puede apreciar tiene tres clases, la clase reproductor, es el padre, y reprodutorjava y reproducirandroid son  las hijas, El problema que tengo es que no se ejecutan las clases hijos

La idea es que se ejecute un hijo dependiendo del tipo de sistema operativo que estoy utilizando, pero no logro hacer que funcione, no se ejecuta ninguna clase hijo, donde esta el problema? he colocado Getinstance se puede ver en el código de la clase padre.
PD:
Tal vez sirva, para llamar a la clase padre lo hago como si fuera un thread. de la siguiente manera

```
reproductor sistemaprincipal = new reproductor();
Thread t = new Thread(sistemaprincipal);
t.start();
```

Comment: Para empezar, `reproducirAndroid` extiende `reproducir`, y la que dices que es la clase base es `reproductor`. ¿Fue un error en la pregunta, o el código está efectivamente así?

Comment: Concuerdo con @MarcosCrispino, debes tener MiClase extends **reproductor**.

Esto está mal **class reproducirJava extends reproducir**, reproducir no es una clase **public void reproducir**, es un método.

Comment: Lo copie mal porque si esta bien En el programa, lo actualiza

Comment: @MarcosCrispino el error es en los pregunta, al recortar el código para hacerlo explícito me equivoque, el error no esta ahí, esta en otra parte, como podrás ver ya lo corregí en la pregunta

Comment: Por lo pronto veo un `return new ReproducirJava();` y un `class reproducirJava extends reproductor()`. ¿Cómo llamas a `getInstance()` sin ser estático?

Comment: como estas usando esas clases? como sabes que no se estan ejecutando los metodos de las clases hijas?

Comment: no se ejecutan porque lo he depurado! no se ejecutan las clases hija, ese es el problema no es un problema de mayusculas!, simplemente no ingresa al bloque ----> reproductor getInstance() { que se encuentra en la clase padre

Comment: Insisto, si no es molestia: ¿Puedes compartir la forma en la que llamas a `getInstance()`?

Comment: Tienes dos soluciones, o hacer el método estático para no tener que crear una instancia del padre para llamar al método o llamar a `getInstance` antes del `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

## Con método estático

```
static reproductor getInstance() {
  System.out.println( "bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.reproductor.getInstance()" );
  if (main.isandroid()) {
    return new reproducirAndroid();
  } else {
    //System.out.println( "bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.reproductor.getInstance()");
    return new ReproducirJava();
  }
}
```

Y se llamaría:

```
Runnable sistemaprincipal = reproductor.getInstance();
Thread t = new Thread(sistemaprincipal);
t.start();
```

## Con instancia del padre

Instanciar el padre es innecesario como puedes ver en el apartado anterior, pero si lo necesitas por algo:

```
reproductor sistemaprincipal = new reproductor();
Thread t = new Thread(sistemaprincipal.getInstance());
t.start();
```

Comment: Gracias, gracias por tu respuesta