# Proyecto java multiplataforma, como hacer clases dependiendo del entorno

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de ejecutar dependiendo del entorno, en una pregunta anterior me plantearon utilizar poliformismo como se puede ver en la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/en-java-utilizar-una-clase-diferente-dependiendo-del-sistema-operativo). 
El problema que tengo es que en el entorno de android necesito ejecutar el comando getApplicationContext(), donde lo requiero en el entorno android únicamente, el tema es que cuando ejecuto la clase en windows, no puedo compilar porque el comando no es reconocido sino es para la plataforma que fue hecho. Entonces la idea que se me surgió es en el proyecto android, solo se incluirá la clase que es para android. El problema que me surge es como ejecutar una clase u otra, dependiendo del entorno.
Aquí va un ejemplo
tengo en el proyecto la clase reproductor de la pregunta citada, "Recortado"

```
public class reproductor implements Runnable {
static reproductor getInstance() {
        //System.out.println("bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.reproductor.getInstance()");
        if (main.isandroid()) {
            System.out.println("reproducir android");
            //return new Class.forName("bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.Sonidoambiental");
return new ReproductorAndroid();
        } else {
                        System.out.println("reproducir java");                
            return new ReproducirJava();
        }
    }
}
```

Clase de escritorio

```
public class ReproducirJava extends reproductor {
}
```

En un subproyecto tengo la siguiente clase
clase android

```
public class ReproductorAndroid extends reproductor{
}
```

obviamente en el sub-proyecto se incluyen las clases del proyecto principal  y se pueden utilizarlas pero en caso contrario al hacer referencia desde el proyecto principal a una clase que esta fuera del proyecto, en este caso el sub-proyecto android, no se como llamarla, y he aquí la cuestión.
en este ejemplo es visible que llamo a la clase ReproductorAndroid pero al estar fuera del proyecto da error, la razón por la que tengo que sacarlo es por el comando ya mencionado, que se ejecuta solo en el entorno android, fuera de este no existe la funcion. Por tal y otras otras requiero colocar unas clases extends del proyecto principal, pero no se como llamarlo, alguien podría ayudarme? me explique lo bastante claro?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a agregar preprocesamiento para una u otra plataforma?

Comment: Si exactamente, a eso me refiero.

Comment: Cuando me dijiste el uso que le ibas a dar te recomendé que la clase común la incluyeras en el jar y la implementación dependiente de cada plataforma la dejaras en cada proyecto en particular. No necesitas un "esandroid" y esa mentalidad te hará irte por caminos muy tortuosos. En el `main` de Java SE instancias la clase de Java SE y en la actividad principal de Android la de Android. Luego sólo tienes que pasar como parámetro `reproductor` la instancia y listo, no tendrás problemas de compilación cruzada.

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema. En la otra pregunta te dijeron que uses polimorfismo, lo cual es lo correcto en este caso. Tendrías una implementación para Windows y otra para Android, por lo cual no deberías llamar a `getApplicationContext` en tu implementación para Windows.
Tomate tu tiempo para aprender un poco más sobre polimorfismo y POO en general y verás que la solución es muy sencilla.

Answer (score -1):

La opción que utilizo yo es un proyecto definiendo las interfaces<sup>1</sup> a implementar/usar en los otros proyectos:

```
proyecto IReproductor ->
  public interface Reproductor {
    public void play();
  }

proyecto ReproductorAndroid (depende de proyecto IReproductor) ->
  public class ReproductorAndroid implements Reproductor {
    ...
  }

proyecto MiApp (depende de proyecto IReproductor) ->
  public class MiApp {
    private Reproductor reproductor;
  }
```

A la hora de empaquetar la aplicación, incluyes el jar del reproductor adecuado a la plataforma.

Lo que queda es instanciar las clases. Aquí la mejor opción<sup>2</sup> es establecer que todas las implementaciones deben implementar un determinado constructor<sup>3</sup>(uno muy usado es el constructor sin parámetros) e invocarlo mediante *reflection*. Aconsejo crear una clase *Factory* con un método que proporcione las instancias, para encapsular la lógica.

El nombre de la clase a instanciar lo puedes pasar de distintas maneras:

- *hard-coded* en el *factory*,
- propiedad del sistema,
- fichero/BD/JNDI de configuración de la aplicación principal,
- fichero de configuración en los *jar*s de implementación, leido mediante *getResourceAsStream*,
- etc.

Por último, en Java EE todo este mecanismo ya está automatizado con el CDI.

---

<sup>1</sup>Mejor interfaces que clases o clases abstractas. Si un par de implementaciones se benefician de que exista una clase abstracta, puedes definir que la clase abstracta implemente la interfaz y que las implementaciones extiendan la clase abstracta.

<sup>2</sup>Otra posible opción sería que todas las implementaciones tuvieran exactamente el mismo nombre y constructor y simplemente empaquetar una versión o la otra según la plataforma. Muy feo.

<sup>3</sup>Asegúrate de documentarlo en el Javadoc de la interfaz, y en los documentos de diseño correspondiente.